# How to build apk file with Apache Cordova

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, apache-cordova

Good day!
I use VS 2015+Apache Cordova. I make simple app and want to get apk of this.
But, when i build peoject- i have not any *apk file at /bin/Android.

I can run my app at Ripple emulator.

Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452084/phonegap-cordova-build-apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is build for device rather than ripple, then you'll see the .apk in the bin and platforms directory.

Just select this from the targets drop down:

[image]

And then select "show all files" in the solution explorer and search for .apk:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I try it when come home.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this online tool by simply uploading your www directory

https://build.phonegap.com/

if you want to  build it locally use Phonegap CLI
 use the following command

```
>phonegap local build android
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
```

Here is a tutorial how to build it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xde05OoqWag

Comment: It is not solution, because it is for remote build, but i need just build it on my local machine